# Is there an equal area basemap for the Alaska region of North America?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, united-states, basemap

I am looking to apply an equal area basemap to my data. Although I do not receive an error when applying the data in the same arcmap document, the data is being spaced in an undesirable fashion. The spacing of the point data is not wrong, I simply want each pixel to represent the same amount of area on the map. To be clear, the points are indeed representing the same area but it is the visual representation of the area which is being affected.

Data without basemap, hence no distortion/seperation between pixels:
[image: Data without basemap, hence no distortion/seperation between pixels]

Data with basemap and distortion between pixels:
[image: Data with basemap and distortion between pixels.]

Comment: Is this simply a display/visualization issue?  Your point symbols will scale visually depending on your zoom level, so you can simply increase the size of your point display to have them appear to be contiguous.  I believe that you could apply the Alaska Albers Equal Area Conic (WKID 3338) to your data frame with or without the basemap and you would be using an equal area display, but I'm not sure this will address your visualization issue (especially at different zoom levels).

Comment: Can you reproject the points into the equal area projection?  This should fix the spacing issue.  I can see that it is latitudinal spacing that is incorrect, so changing the point symbols won't help.  It's also hard to tell the differences in your images because they are at different scales.  Can you show a screenshot of the first image, but zoomed to the scale of the second image?